# Undefined reference to?

Tags: c++

I am writing a code for a dice roll cootie game in C++ but I keep running into the error code "undefined reference to 'cootieComplete(int)'" & I am not sure how to fix it. 
The assignment is to create a cootie game where you roll the dice and then apply it to add different body parts to the cootie.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int rolldice();
int applyroll(int);
bool cootieComplete(int);
void printCootie(int);

        int numBody=0;
        int numHead=0;
        int numAntenna=0;
        int numWings=0;
        int numTongue=0;
        int numLeg=0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int diceroll;
   int apply;
   srand(time(0));
   do {
   diceroll = rolldice();
   apply = applyroll(diceroll);
   printCootie(diceroll);
   }
   while (!cootieComplete(apply)) ;


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

     int rolldice()
 {
     int diceroll = rand() % 6 + 1;
     return diceroll;
}

    int applyroll(int diceroll){

                   if (diceroll == 1)
                   {
                    numBody++;
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 2 && numBody >= 1)
                   {
                    numHead++;
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 3 && numHead >=1)
                   {
                    numAntenna++;
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 4 && numBody >= 1)
                   {
                    numWings++;
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 5 && numHead >= 1)
                   {
                    numTongue++;
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 6 && numBody >= 1)
                   {
                    numLeg++;
                   }
            return diceroll;
            }

     bool cootieComplete(int numBody,int numHead,int numAntenna,int numWings,int numTongue,int numLeg) {
         if (numBody>0&&numHead>0&&numAntenna>1&&numWings>1&&numTongue!=0&&numLeg>=4) {
             return true;
          }
         else {
               return false;
          }
    }

    void printCootie(int diceroll){

                   if (diceroll == 1)
                   {
                    cout << "Body Added!" << endl;
                    cout << "There are " << numBody << " body, " << numHead << " head, " << numAntenna << " antenna, " << numWings << " wings, " << numTongue << " tongues, " << numLeg << " legs." << endl;
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 2 && numBody >= 1)
                   {
                    cout << "Head Added!" << endl;
                    cout << "There are " << numBody << " body, " << numHead << " head, " << numAntenna << " antenna, " << numWings << " wings, " << numTongue << " tongues, " << numLeg << " legs." << endl;
                   }
                   else if (diceroll == 2)
                   {
                    cout <<"No body, you can't add head!";
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 3 && numHead >=1)
                   {
                    cout << "Antenna Added!"<<endl;
                    cout << "There are " << numBody << " body, " << numHead << " head, " << numAntenna << " antenna, " << numWings << " wings, " << numTongue << " tongues, " << numLeg << " legs." << endl;
                   }
                   else if (diceroll == 3)
                   {
                    cout << "No head, you can't add antenna!";
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 4 && numBody >= 1)
                   {
                    cout<<"Wing Added!" << endl;
                    cout << "There are " << numBody << " body, " << numHead << " head, " << numAntenna << " antenna, " << numWings << " wings, " << numTongue << " tongues, " << numLeg << " legs." << endl;
                   }
                   else if (diceroll == 4)
                   {
                    cout << "No body, you can't add wings!";
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 5 && numHead >= 1)
                   {
                    cout<<"Tongue Added!" << endl;
                    cout << "There are " << numBody << " body, " << numHead << " head, " << numAntenna << " antenna, " << numWings << " wings, " << numTongue << " tongues, " << numLeg << " legs." << endl;
                   }
                   else if (diceroll == 5)
                   {
                    cout << "No head, you can't add tongue!";
                   }

                   if (diceroll == 6 && numBody >= 1)
                   {
                    cout<<"Leg Added!" << endl;
                    cout << "There are " << numBody << " body, " << numHead << " head, " << numAntenna << " antenna, " << numWings << " wings, " << numTongue << " tongues, " << numLeg << " legs." << endl;
                   }
                   else if (diceroll == 6)
                   {
                    cout << "No body, you can't add legs";
                   }

     }
```

Comment: Believe me, you don't really want/need those global variables.

Answer (score 6):

You **declare** cootieComplete to take 1 int and you **define** it to take 6 then you call the version taking 1.

```
// Declaration
bool cootieComplete(int);

...

while (!cootieComplete(apply))

....

// Definition
bool cootieComplete(int numBody,int numHead,int numAntenna,int numWings,int numTongue,int numLeg)
```

Since you called the version taking 1 int as parameter, compiler is looking for the definition of `cootieComplete(int)` but can't find it so throw the `undefined reference` error.

They need to match. So define it like so:

```
bool cootieComplete(int, int, int, int, int, int);
```

Answer (score 1):

Eric is correct, if you need them to match. Make them look like

```
bool cootieComplete(int, int, int, int, int, int);

bool cootieComplete(int numBody,int numHead,int numAntenna,int numWings,int numTongue,int numLeg){
  // Code here
}
```

That should fix your error

Comment: It still throwing the error " too few arguments to function 'bool cootieComplete(int, int, int, int, int, int)'

Comment: @user3060043 did you look at all the stuff Eric said?

Comment: Yes I changed it so they match

Comment: " too few arguments to function 'bool cootieComplete(int, int, int, int, int, int)'

Comment: And what does that line that is calling cootieComplete look like now?